# How do I delete an array inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to delete an array entry.
I have already used the splice method, but it doesn't work.

```
var clients = new Array();
//-----

var tmp = new Array();
tmp["connection"] = connection;
tmp["authentificated"] = 1;
tmp["username"] = rows[0].username;
tmp["rank"] = rows[0].rank;
clients.push(tmp);
```

This doesn't work:

```
clients.splice(index, 1);
```

Do you have any ideas, where the mistake is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what is on `index`?

Comment: It'd be better if you use `tmp` as an object not an array.

Comment: You have an array inside an array. Call `delete clients[0]['username'];` or use an object.

Comment: *"This doesn't work"* . Show [mcve]

Comment: Thank you all. Yes, you're right. An explanation of "index" would have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below.

```
var clients = new Array();


var tmp = new Array();
tmp["connection"] = "hi";
tmp["authentificated"] = 1;

clients.push(tmp);

var tmp1 = new Array();
tmp1["connection"] = "hi";
tmp1["authentificated"] = 2;

clients.push(tmp1);
var index = 0;
delete clients[index];

console.log(clients);
```

but the issue with delete is that the length of the array will remain same because delete only removes the object from the element in the array